# Add space and change the font in this code

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I need to add a space and change the font to a smaller one, with italics.

Here is my code:

```
    $output .= '<tr> '.
    '   <td class="contentfont">&nbsp;&raquo; <a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']] . '</a>'.$cat_details['items_counter'].'</td> '.
    '</tr> ';
```

I would like to add a space and change the font for this portion:

```
</a>'.$cat_details['items_counter'].'</td>
```

How should I do this?

Comment: wasn't sure which css was being called so i used the method below; will this hurt the sites performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `</a>`, add `&nbsp;<font size="#"><em>`, and right before the `</td>`, add `</em></font>`?

It's practical.

Comment: And dirty. He can use CSS for this.

Comment: I don't think he minds not having to use CSS. He asked for a solution, so I gave him one ;)

Comment: I'm not saying that it isn't a solution or that it won't work. But using CSS is cleaner. Who doesn't use it nowadays? :) Cheers. :)

Comment: I usually don't if it's 3 in the morning and I just want to get something done, but that's true. I try to stay away from what I did in my example but laziness conquers me.

Comment: for some reason the css was not working so i used this method

Answer (score 2):

Put the items counter in a span, and give it a class:

```
$output .= '<tr> '.
    '   <td class="contentfont">&nbsp;&raquo; <a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']] . '</a><span class="items_counter">'.$cat_details['items_counter'].'</span></td> '.
    '</tr> ';
```

And then set the style you want to that class:

```
<style>
.items_counter {
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 0 2px; /* change 2px by whatever you want */
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

just append an additional space, sounds dirty but that would do it:

```
. ' ' . $cat_details['items_counter'] . ' ' .
```

and for making the font smaller, why not use css?

```
td.contentfont{
    font-size: 2px;
    font-style: italic
}
```

Comment: Spaces can be added using CSS. It's cleaner and more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a `<span class="classNameThatMakesFontFaceWhatYouWant">...</span>`, and add the spaces, wherever you want.

```
$output .= '<tr> '.
    '   <td class="contentfont">&nbsp;&raquo; <a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']] . '</a>'. ' <span class="classNameThatMakesFontFaceWhatYouWant">' . $cat_details['items_counter'] . ' </span>' . '</td> '.
    '</tr> ';
```